# MS Project VBA 'Predecessor' or Dependency.Path Fields Update Not Working

Tags: vba, task, ms-project

I am trying to overwrite the tsk.Predecessors and/or dep.Path field value of a Task. Using the Predecessor for an example, my update field code is as follows:

- tsk.Predecessors = "Replacement string"
- tsk.SetField pjTaskPredecessors, Value:= "Replacement string"

The referenced "tsk" value (and "dep" value below) have been Dimensioned for the Task and Predecessor Objects.

No matter what I do, the 'tsk.Predecessors' or 'dep.Path' field values will not update.

Is there some prerequisite to enabling the 'tsk.Predecessors' or 'dep.Path' field to update?

Or does MS Project not permit update of the 'tskPredecessors' or 'dep.Path' field via a VBA Macro.

Any feedback most welcomed.

-Wayne

Comment: Both of those fields are read-write. Try testing with a very simple project. If still having issues, update your question with the code that isn't working. Also include information about what error you are getting.

Comment: Thanks, Rachel! I'll create a Test simple Project tomorrow and then upload the code as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for further input on this topic. After additional testing, determined that Projects requiring an update of the  'tsk.Predecessors' or 'dep.Path' fields, had the prerequisite that all Projects needed to be open at the time of the update.